# h:selectOneMenu onchange="submit()" immediate="true" does not skip validation of other inputs

Tags: jsf-2, selectonemenu

I can't set my `h:selectOneMenu` to submit immediately without validating other inputs. Here is the code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{a.avalue}" onchange="submit()" immediate="true">   
    <f:selectItems value="#{b.bvalue}" var="k" itemLabel="#{k.asdad}"  
        itemValue="#{k.asdad}"/>   
</h:selectOneMenu>   
<h:inputText id="sada" value="#{c.cvalue}" required="true"  
    requiredMessage="*asdadadadasd"  
    validatorMessage="*asdsadadadadad">   
    <f:validateLength maximum="80"/>   
</h:inputText>
```

When I change the menu value, the validators of other inputs still fire. How can I deny that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `immediate="true"` on current input component doesn't stop validators of other input components from firing. It only causes that the current input component will be validated one phase before than usual. Basically, you need to attach a `valueChangeListener` to the input component and then call `FacesContext#renderResponse()` in the listener method so that the processing of all other input components will be skipped.

But as you're already using JSF 2.0, much better/easier is to use ajax powers instead of this old fashioned JSF 1.x approach.

E.g.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.country}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.countries}" var="country" itemLabel="#{country.name}" itemValue="#{country.code}"/>
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.changeCountry}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

with

```
public void changeCountry() {
    System.out.println("Selected country is: " + country);
}
```

If you'd like to re-render some parts of the form whenever the selection is changed, then use the `render` attribute. E.g.

```
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.changeCountry}" render="otherComponentId" />
```

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/11883021#11883021)