# "onchange" not working for selectOneMenu in PrimeFaces 3.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My selectOneMenu isn't fireing an onchange event. Here is the code:

```
 <p:selectOneMenu id="select_preset" 
                  value="#{JobMgmtBean.presetGroupName}" 
                  valueChangeListener="#{PFJobMgmtBean.PresetGroupChangeEvent}" 
                  onchange="submit();">
    <f:selectItems value="#{JobMgmtBean.presetGroupList}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The selectOneMenu is nicely populated, and I can select different values. But I would expect that after I change a selection, page would be refreshed, i.e. backing bean (RequestScoped) would be recreated (onchange="submit();")? But nothing happens when selection in the selectOneMenu is changed.

Also, value change listener PresetGroupChangeEvent() is not called.

Did I go wrong somewhere?

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.25 + MyFaces 2.1.6 + PrimeFaces 3.2.

Comment: Please check the similar issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687980/hselectonemenu-onchange-submit-immediate-true-does-not-skip-validation-of

Comment: Did you try with h:selectOneMenu?

Answer (score 10):

try to remove

```
onchange="submit();"
```

and to add

```
<p:ajax update="@this"/>
```

from your p:selectOneMenu when you using primefaces

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="select_preset" 
              value="#{JobMgmtBean.presetGroupName}" 
              valueChangeListener="#{PFJobMgmtBean.PresetGroupChangeEvent}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{JobMgmtBean.presetGroupList}"/>
    <p:ajax update="@this"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

check your listener signature (starts from big "P" ?)

```
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
public void PresetGroupChangeEvent(ValueChangeEvent event) { }
```

Comment: In the meantime, I switched to Ajax and it works nicely. I will check your answer if needed later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

why you are not adding update attribute using p:ajax? I think rerendering components more better solution than refreshing, also you can just rerender needed components. But if you still want to refresh page you can also use javascript:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="select_preset" value="#{JobMgmtBean.presetGroupName}" onchange="window.location.reload();">
    <f:selectItems value="#{JobMgmtBean.presetGroupList}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

and just for updating necessary components:

```
 <p:selectOneMenu id="select_preset" value="#{JobMgmtBean.presetGroupName}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{JobMgmtBean.presetGroupList}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change" update="@form" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Too late now to go for Ajax changes for me. Do you see anthing wrong with `onchange="submit();`?

Comment: try onchange="this.submit();"

Comment: Thanks but `onchange="this.submit();"` doesn't help.

Comment: This `onchange="window.location.reload();"` works, it refreshes the page, but I am not sure if that's the same as `submit()`. I am still not getting any value change listener events... why? :-(.

Comment: Sorry for late answer without looking into your page I can not say anything, but I would advice use just one h:form (if you dont have use it:)) with attribute: prependId="false". Review your logic to make sure its not because of requestscope as its garbaging per http request. I would try first sessionscope or viewscope just to see page functionality. try <p:ajax event="change" action="#{PFJobMgmtBean.PresetGroupChangeEvent}" /> if presetGroupList is not a string list add itemlabel and item value attributes.

Comment: I switched to using Ajax. Ajax works. However, submit() still doesn't work and this issue stays unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="select_preset" 
                  value="#{JobMgmtBean.presetGroupName}" 
                  valueChangeListener="#{PFJobMgmtBean.PresetGroupChangeEvent}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{JobMgmtBean.presetGroupList}"/>
        <p:ajax process="select_preset" partialSubmit="true" event="valueChange"  update="yourComponentName"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use ajax from primefaces and refresh only what you want to refresh