# Primefaces SelectOneMenu: Selected item is not set in Managed Bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I am programming a SelectOneMenu in an overlayPanel. The problem is that the selected value is always null in the bean. The setter method is not called, so i think that the SelectOneMenu is not submitted when i select an item.

Here is my page:

```
    <p:overlayPanel id="OverLayPanelNewRole" for="buttonAddRole">

                <p:selectOneMenu id="SelectOneMenuRoles" value="#{userSettingBean.selectedRole}" 
                onchange="submit()" immediate="true">

                   <f:selectItems value="#{userSettingBean.roleList}" var="role" itemLabel="#{role.NAME}" style="width:100%"/>

               </p:selectOneMenu>       
    </p:overlayPanel>
```

My Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userSettingBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserSettingBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7579402702068562565L;

    @ManagedProperty(value= "#{roleServiceImpl}")
    private RoleService roleService; 

    private List<Role> roleList;
    private Role selectedRole;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

        //init Roles for selection in overlayPanel
        roleList=roleService.findAllRole();
    }

    public RoleService getRoleService() {
        return roleService;
    }

    public void setRoleService(RoleService roleService) {
        this.roleService = roleService;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoleList() {
        return roleList;
    }

    public void setRoleList(List<Role> roleList) {
        this.roleList = roleList;
    }

    public Role getSelectedRole() {
        return selectedRole;
    }

    public void setSelectedRole(Role selectedRole) {
        this.selectedRole = selectedRole;
    }
```

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: post your managed bean code first.

Comment: I need to show a list of roles who are dynamicly generated, so i can not use `<f:selectItem>` because i don't know how many roles are shown.

Comment: Try removing immediate=true

Comment: Where is the `<h:form/>` in this picture? The most probable culprit here is a conversion/validation error and seeing as you're submitting the entire form using `submit()` (which is entirely unnecessary, you should be using ajax instead), any component on the page may be blocking the form submission

Comment: @phoenix yes, it works without the immediate="true". Thanks a lot!
@kolossus that is only a part of my page. Actually there is another datatable in the page. And around the datatable and the overlayPanel there is the `<h:form>`.

Comment: @kolossus what would be the command if i don't want to update the whole form and use ajax instead?

Comment: @hiaslosch17 nothing. Just add a `<p:ajax update="@form"/>`

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post it as the answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the comments, removing immediate="true" corrected the issue in this case. However, using onchange="submit()" should be replaced with <f:ajax> if using jsf 2.0+. See the relevant post here:

[h:selectOneMenu onchange="submit()" immediate="true" does not skip validation of other inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687980/hselectonemenu-onchange-submit-immediate-true-does-not-skip-validation-of)