# Getter method returns null when called from action listener

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an application with a p:selectOneMenu component. This component is used to determine what category of file is being uploaded so I can do some work to it when the file is uploaded.

I implemented the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687980/hselectonemenu-onchange-submit-immediate-true-does-not-skip-validation-of) and it seems to call my setter methods correctly for fileType. But once the file is submitted and the handleFileUpload method is called, the fileType getter method returns null.

For example, if I select Foo then I get the output

```
File type changed to: Foo
```

But when I hit the upload button I get the output

```
The file type selected is null
```

When I expect

```
The file type selected is Foo
```

What is causing the get method to return two different results and is there a way to fix this?

**main.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh"
        content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval};url=index.xhtml" />
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <title>File Upload</title>
        </h:head>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <ui:insert name="pagebody" />
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/templates/main.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="pagebody">     
        <h:body>
            <h:form id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
                    <h:outputText value="File Type:" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{uploadBean.fileType}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Foo" itemValue="Foo"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bar" itemValue="Bar"/>
                        <f:ajax listener="#{uploadBean.changeFileType}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <br />
                <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{uploadBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"/> 
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**UploadBean.java**

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "uploadBean")
public class UploadBean implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String fileType = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
    }

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event){
        System.out.println("The file type selected is " + this.getFileType());
    }

    public String getFileType() {
        return fileType;
    }

    public void setFileType(String fileType) {
        this.fileType = fileType;
    }

    public void changeFileType() {
        System.out.println("File type changed to: " + this.getFileType());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I never considered this being the issue. Switching my bean to view scoped cleared up my issue.

Comment: Yes, if you submit the file in advanced mode (via ajax), this is a new request in which the other input fields are not submitted (as mentioned in the duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Kukeltje the issue was that my bean was not properly scoped. Switching from RequestScoped to ViewScoped fixed the issue I was having.

Comment: Hi, as this question is a duplicate of another one and in the process as being marked as such, there is no need to answer the question.